# Add seconds to an existing date in Lua

Tags: lua

I want to calculate time in Lua.

For example: I want to get the current date (incl. at least seconds) and then I want to add seconds to this date that I get a date which is in the future.

Comment: Did you try anything? For instance, do you know how to get the current date?

Comment: of corse - i know that i can get the current date with os.time() - tried to add a number to it, but i didnt work..

Comment: In the future, add the code that you tried (even if it's not working right now) to the question, so that people know what exactly the problem was and your attempted effort. Questions that show no effort could easily be closed.

Comment: okay, im sorry .. will do it in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
now=os.time()
print(os.date("%c",now))
print(os.date("%c",now+10000))
```

Comment: ah thank u, works fine now. made the C in capital letter.. can u maybe explain what the "%C" is doing? thanks